# Error Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql

Buen día a todos, tengo este problema cuando trato de establecer conexión a un equipo donde instale `XAMPP` para alojar un servidor de base de datos `MYSQL` de forma local y así mismo una base de datos para un reloj checador, a traves de `PHPMYADMIN` si puedo acceder a la base de datos, tablas y registros, pero necesito desarrollar una interfaz donde el responsable de nominas pueda filtrar los registros de checadas, ingresando al servidor de base de datos de manera remota por medio de la dirección `IP` del equipo, a continuación dejo el codigo que estoy usando.

```
MySqlConnection cadenaconexion;

        /*Abrir conexión con la BD*/
        public Conexion()
        {
            try
            {
                //conectado = false;
                cadenaconexion = new MySqlConnection ("Server=1.1.1.1;Database=relojchecador;Uid=root;Pwd=password,Port=3306");
                cadenaconexion.Open();
                //conectado = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Se realizo la conexión con exito");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Gracias de nuevo por su valiosa ayuda y poder establecer la conexión de forma correcta.

Comment: Es una IP del equipo donde instale XAMPP y donde esta alojada la BD el 1.1.1.1 es a modo de ejemplo, la BD no esta en mi equipo local sino en otro equipo dentro de mi red.

Comment: Hmm..estas intentando acceder como root desde otro equipo? Eso a veces está desautorizado, intenta con otro usuario

Comment: Tengo que crear otro usuario entonces para poder acceder??

Comment: Si, eso sería lo recomendable por cuestiones de seguridad. Mira mi respuesta de todas maneras

Comment: Ahora este es el error: Host is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es probablemente en intentar acceder como `root` desde fuera de `localhost`. Esto por cuestion de seguridad no está permitido por defecto. Para solucionarlo tienes dos opciones, crear un nuevo usuario y acceder con el (**recomendado**) o habilitar el acceso root externo,para lo cual traduzco de [una respuesta de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11225588/579895):

Hacen falta 2 pasos:

a) Dar los privilegios. Como root ejecuta:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

b) bind a todas las direcciones:

La manera mas sencilla es comentar la linea siguiente en `my.cnf`:

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

y reiniciar el servicio mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: Ahora me muestra este error: Host is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server.

Comment: Estas usando ahora otro usuario?  Si es asi,debes hacer la parte de dar privilegios cambiando root por tu usuario

Comment: Perdona las molestias, ya hice la configuración y ahora me lanza un nuevo error: Authentication to host '1.1.1.1' for user using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user using password